# UDP reading blocks forever

Tags: go, networking, udp

I have a simple UDP struct I made in Go, and when I run the following code, it blocks forever. For reference, the address of my server is running on the same computer running the client, but the server listens on a different port and address than the one that is bound to by the client.

```golang
var client Clientee

client.Create("the address of my server")

err, messages := client.Read() // <-- HERE IT BLOCKS FOREVER
if err != nil { panic(err) }

fmt.Printf("Messages: %s", messages)
```

Here's the part of the code that declares my struct:

```golang
package controllers

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

const (
    BUF_SIZE = 1024
    CLIENT_PORT = "4097"
    SERVER_PORT = "4096"
)

type Clientee struct {
    ClServerAddr *net.UDPAddr
    ClLocalAddr *net.UDPAddr
    ClConn *net.UDPConn
    ClWasShutdown bool
}

// Initialize and connect the Clientee
func (c *Clientee) Create(hostAddr string) error {
    var err error

    c.ClWasShutdown=false

    // Resolve the server's address
    c.ClServerAddr, err = net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", hostAddr+":"+SERVER_PORT)
    if err != nil { return err }
    fmt.Println("Server addr = ",c.ClServerAddr.String())

    // Resolve our local address
    c.ClLocalAddr, err = net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":"+CLIENT_PORT)
    if err != nil { return err }

    // Create the connection
    c.ClConn, err = net.ListenUDP("udp", c.ClLocalAddr)
    if err != nil { return err }

    // Pause
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*200)

    return nil
}

// Send a message to the Server
func (c *Clientee) Send(msg string) error {
    _, err := c.ClConn.WriteToUDP([]byte(msg), c.ClServerAddr)
    if err!=nil { return err }

    return nil
}

// Read messages from the Server
func (c *Clientee) Read() (error, string) {
    bfr:=make([]byte, BUF_SIZE) // Make the buffer
    n, addr, err := c.ClConn.ReadFromUDP(bfr)
    if err!=nil { return err, "" }

    // If the message doesn't come from the server, don't return it
    if addr.String()!=c.ClServerAddr.String() {
        return nil, ""
    }

    return nil, string(bfr[0:n])
}

// Close the Connection.
func (c *Clientee) Close() error {
        return c.ClConn.Close()
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? The call will only return when data is received and you make no mention of anything sending data. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [This](https://play.golang.org/p/TU8mFbb9jAB) might be a good starting point (works OK for me).

Comment: I didn't know it was blocking. Is there a way to figure out if there's data or not asynchronously? I call `Read()` periodically, and ideally it'll give me the data sent since it was last called.

Comment: @user96931: you use goroutines in Go to do something asynchronously.

Comment: I've never thought of that. Thankyou! If you'd post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ReadFromUDP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.ReadFromUDP) will block until something is received. The [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.ReadFromUDP) refer you to [ReadFrom](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.ReadFrom) which says "ReadFrom implements the PacketConn ReadFrom method.". Looking at the [PacketConn](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#PacketConn) docs you will find the following:

> ReadFrom reads a packet from the connection, copying the payload into
>   p. It returns the number of bytes copied into p and the return address
>   that was on the packet. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <=
>   len(p)) and any error encountered. Callers should always process the n > 0
>   bytes returned before considering the error err.
>
> ReadFrom can be made to time out and return an Error with Timeout() == true after a
>   fixed time limit; see SetDeadline and SetReadDeadline.

So if you do not want this to block (as per the comments) then you can either:

- Use `SetDeadline` or `SetReadDeadline` to set a deadline.
- Run `ReadFromUDP` within a goroutine and handle data as it's received (which may include putting received data onto a channel)

Note: Calling `ReadFromUDP` with a zero length buffer may not block but this depends upon the [operating system implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23849) so is probably not something to rely on.